# Where is the source code for logPerformance in @apify/scraper-tool

Tags: apify

I am trying to understand how to use `tools.logPerformance(request, 'gotoFunction INIT', start);` so i can better understand the performance of my actors.

I found the function is in apify/scraper-tools. But I am unable to locate the source and not documented in the API/SDK:

```
const {
    tools,
    createContext,
    constants: { META_KEY },
} = require('@apify/scraper-tools');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the code in [Apify Scrapers repo](https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper/tree/master/scraper-tools). This is not part of the SDK and it is not publicly exposed. You are free to use it if you find it helpful. Just keep in mind it is built directly for the Scrapers (for some reason) and not the SDK as whole.